# Pandas filter vs. loc method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Does anyone know the fundamental difference between the .filter method and the .loc method in Pandas?  They seem to do the same thing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.loc[]` is a [Purely label-location based indexer for selection by label](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc). It fails when the selection isn't found, only accepts certain types of input and works on only one axis of your dataframe.

`df.filter()` returns  [Subset rows or columns of dataframe according to labels in the specified index.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) You can filter along either axis, and you can filter in more advanced ways than with `loc`.

`filter` will return the same type of object as the caller, whereas `loc` will return the value specified by the label (so a Series if caller is a DF, a scalar if caller is a Series).

In short, `.loc` is for accessing a specific item within the caller, `.filter()` is for applying a filter to the caller and returning only items  which match that filter.

Comment: What do you mean by item and caller please?

Comment: In this context `df` is the caller, i.e. it is the object which is calling the `loc` or `filter` methods. Item, in this context, refers to the specific row/rows in `df` which are returned by the caller.

Comment: Do operations like cell value change on the Subset affect the original dataframe?

Comment: Filter allows you to use regex.